# Handing Drawing / Painting / Saving of multiple bitmaps

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-asynctask

**Goal:**

I want to draw / write / paint on bitmaps from pdf and save them together so I could send them email.

**Details:**

I have multiple `Pdf` files containing `5-20` pages each, right now am extracting bitmaps from `pdfs` and loading them in fragments in `ViewPager`,
where I can swipe through them and write / draw or whatever I want. To save / restore the current state of the bitmap I'm using `onSaveInstanceState`.
This way I'm able to retrieve the last stage of the bitmap while swiping back and forth.

Something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("Bitmap", bitmap);
    }
```

**Problem:**

User presses send email button in and I should  be able to save all the images regardless of which page he is on i.e. he has edited the page 5 to 10
and now he is on page 10 and press the send button I should be able to retrieve all the edited images.

**Problem 2:**

As I have stated the number of images are about 5-20, Saving the state in `onSaveInstanceState` works great but it keeps increasing the app memory in ram, and the app crashes at 10th image where the app size goes to `150Mbs`.

But saving the image as bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` is also necessary because it helps for faster loading of images when user swipes back n forth.

> So I was thinking is there any way we can create a custom bundle
>   class where we can write the image to disk after say 5 pages scrolled
>   and clears  the memory and read it back from disk to memory when user
>   is scrolling back? does this sound any reasonable?

**What I have tried:**

As bitmaps are loaded in seperate fragments I tried to save the bitmaps to external storage in `OnDestroy`, but as saving bitmaps to disk is not a small task, it takes time though am using `AsyncTask`
but when user is swiping bit fast between fragments then saving bitmaps in `OnDestroy` does not seems like a convinient way.

This is why I'm asking the question so maybe you have better understanding of the situation and can help me achieve this in a more convinient way.

So what do you purpose how I can handle this situation?

**Note:**

if you have trouble understanding the situation and need more info leave me a comment and I will update the question.

Thanks

Comment: I have the following questions for you. 1. are you scaling down the images  and displaying to viewpager according to layout width/height. if not you have to do it(which will reduce bitmap memory consumption).

Comment: 2. Lets say you have a canvas over each image,  user paints something over it , r u saving the changes to the image when the user swipe to next one. (This practice will increase the image size).

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe how i am seeing the solution of this issue now.

There should be a `Service` which takes an **edited** bitmap with some *id* (same for all modifications of original bitmap), adds it to queue and then each item of that queue it persists to the external storage. It has limited `Executor` instance which executes that tasks (them could be just `Runnable`) and `Service` creates a `HashMap` where maps `Future` of task to bitmap identifier. So when new `Bitmap` has came, `Service` checks the map and replaces waiting task (with same original bitmap) if any have existed.

You can send a task to this `Service` from `destroyItem` interceptor of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

So, when user clicks on save button you should also send all edited bitmaps left to this `Service` and just wait for completion.

Comment: I'm also thinking the same, what you think of [Tap](http://square.github.io/tape/)?

Comment: @MaxRockwood looks well, like a flat wrapper around of an android service, square almost always creates a good stuff thought. But i haven't used it before

Comment: yeah the queue system seems promising regarding the situation I have, I will give it a shot and post the update.